# How to plot a directed graph with the designated start point in R

Tags: r, igraph, directed-graph

Here is the data I use to test,which is in graph.txt:

```
1 2
1 3
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
5 6
5 10
6 7
7 8
7 9
7 12
8 9
9 10
9 4
9 12
10 11
11 2
11 12
```

I use the `graph.data.frame` to plot the directed graph. the code is:

```
 xlist<-read.table("graph.txt")
 xlist <- graph.data.frame(xlist)
 plot(xlist)
```

It can only plot the graph as followed
[image]
But I only want to plot the start point is `5` ,that is `5->6->...` and '`5->10->...`, how can I do to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

With the `igraph` package, the following worked:

```
xlist<-read.table("graph.txt")
xlist.sub <- subset(xlist,V1>=5)
xlist.sub <- graph.data.frame(xlist.sub)
plot(xlist.sub)
```

It is enough to remove all the columns from the data frame that have a node with a number smaller than 5 as their root. It is important that you do the subsetting before applying `graph.data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you!!! But this one just is a test example, what I want is the way to deal with general situations.

Comment: @Cheng What do you want to generalize - cutting graphs at nodes with high betweenness centrality?

Comment: @lukeA thank you for your answer! Maybe this test data is not suitable.  Yes, I just want to plot the designated start point without intercepting the data set.

Comment: @Cheng: Sorry, I did not realize you were looking for a more general solution. What I did is admittedly not particularly useful...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to exclude 1 to 4. Here's another one:

```
xlist<-read.table(text = "1 2
1 3
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
5 6
5 10
6 7
7 8
7 9
7 12
8 9
9 10
9 11
9 12
10 11
11 7
11 12")
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(xlist)
set.seed(1)
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(g, layout = coords)
plot(induced.subgraph(g, setdiff(V(g), 1:4)), 
     layout = coords[-(1:4), ])
```

[image]